# can't access non HTTP only cookie even when response/request headers show it

Tags: express, cookies

I have my express server setting both HTTP only and non HTTP only cookies. I even see both of them in the request/response headers, but when trying to access the non HTTP only programatically through `document.cookie` it doesn't show.

Example of a response:
[image]

`document.cookie`
[image]

And in case it matters, here's the express js code that sets the cookie:

```
res.cookie(DOES_SESSION_EXIST_COOKIE_KEY, true, {
      secure: true,
      sameSite: "none" as any,
      httpOnly: false,
      // 10 years
      maxAge: 10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60,
    })
```

Comment: The cookie is set by a cross-origin request and is therefore not visible in the Javascript of the document's origin (https://brea-th-tool-editor.surge.sh), because it is a cookie for the server's origin (which you don't show in your question).

Comment: but same site is set to `none`

Comment: `SameSite=None` only means that the cookie is set in the browser, it does not imply that you can access it via Javascript from another document origin.